# How to see the history of all files/folders and programs that where added to pc?

Tags: windows, history

I noticed a big jump in used space on my C: drive and i want to see what is the cause of that. Is there a way to see the history of all files/folders and programs added to my pc?
(Using Windows 10)

Comment: See this, as close as it gets>>>>https://windirstat.net/

Comment: You could **start out** WAY more simple that what is being suggested here.  Open "add and remove programs".. sort by size.  See if there is something giant there that is unexpected.  If not, windirstat, and tree size pro are OK.. but I like Scanner [here is the download](http://www.steffengerlach.de/freeware/scn2.zip) for that but if you don't trust me (you shouldn't) [here](http://www.steffengerlach.de/freeware/) is the page it comes from.  Its WAY WAY easier to visualize than those other two tools. Also tree size pro isn't free.

Comment: The price is modest and it comes with Support which is very valuable.

Answer (score 0):

I like and recommend Tree Size Pro and I have used it for some years.  Once you have run it a few times, it creates a history and you can analyze that in some detail.

Current point in time results are excellent and show you both a sorted Explorer view as well as a Chart.

Results can be sorted by Users (not meaningful on a one user machine), Age of File, Top Files and so on. "Age" allows you to see big changes recently very quickly.

WinDirStat (mentioned in the comment here) is free and is good, but I like Tree Size much better as its flexibility fits me very well. It is an excellent reliable piece of software and very much worth the modest price which incudes Support from Jam Software.

Tree Size can be found at Jam Software.